# Webpage not available from Apache Server

Tags: html, windows, apache, web, centos

To give a little background information:
I have a Windows directory (Host OS) that I am sharing to CentOS (Guest OS) that serves as my local web server. For some odd reason, I cannot access any of the files in that share from a web browser. For example, if my address is http://192.168.1.200/home.html it gives me a "Forbidden: You don't have permission to view this page" error. When accessing the shared directory from Linux and try to perform a chmod -R 777 on the parent folder, I receive an access denied even running as root. The Windows side of the house has "Authenticated Users" and "Everyone" with full control. And this is with the assumption that the /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf is modified correctly.

Outside of this, if I just SCP the contents to the server and modify the httpd.conf file to reflect the new directory, I am able to access everything. The point of this is to be able to modify the local file on the Host OS and not having to SCP it over. Essentially, everything is updated on the server automatically when I save it on the Host OS side.

Comment: How is the share setup?  VirtualBox shared directory, samba, nfs, ...?  All this is obviously a permission issue of some sort but we need to know how you did it.

Comment: It is shared through a CIF share from Host OS (Windows 10) to Guest OS (Vmware CentOS)